# Null PointerExeption ALL the time?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Why is `mainB_news` allways `null`? (in the method `onBackPressed()`)
In `onCreate` I set a value to the button!!! :(

PS:  with `findViewById()` I get the same error...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mainB_news;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mainB_news = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainB_news);
        mainB_news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.news);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // check if page 2 is open
        if (mainB_news != null && mainB_news.isShown()){
            setContentView(R.layout.main); // open main view again
            return;
        }else
            super.onBackPressed(); // allows standard use of backbutton for page 1


    }
}
```

THANKS a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you change contentView on button click. `mainB_news` doesn't exist after contentView changing. You shouldn't use `setContentView()` in this manner. Consider using another activity for showing news.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not defined in res/layout/main.xml ?